# java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect when running .java web service client

Tags: eclipse, proxy

I created .java WS client to hit external SOAP request. my laptop is beyond proxy. i went through all the documentation and tried all the solutions of setting up proxy in window->Preferences->general->network connections. 
None of them are working.I am getting required output if i use wireless (out of corp network)

I am able to access the URL from browser even with proxy settings: 
I tried setting up http, HTTPs and SOCKS proxy with userids(domain\username), password and tried also native option. None of them are working.

solutions tried:
1. setting up proxy in windows->preferences->general->networks
2. added eclipse to firewall
3. disabled anti virus
4. added vmargs -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true in eclipse.ini

Any help is appreciated.

Below is my .java file
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
package narsiRestApiTest;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

public class HttpGetter {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String sXML = HttpGetter
                .getDoc("http://api.geonames.org/weatherIcao?ICAO=LSZH&username=rheh&style=full");

        Document dom = HttpGetter.loadXMLFromString(sXML);

        Element el = (Element) dom.getDocumentElement();

        System.out.println(HttpGetter.getTextValue(el, "stationName"));
        System.out.println(HttpGetter.getTextValue(el, "temperature"));

    }

    public static String getDoc(String urlToRead) {

        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection conn;
        BufferedReader rd;
        String line;
        String result = "";

        try {

            url = new URL(urlToRead);
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

            rd = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                result += line;
            }

            rd.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        return result;
    }


    public static Document loadXMLFromString(String xml) throws Exception {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml));
        return builder.parse(is);
    }

    private static String getTextValue(Element ele, String tagName) {
        String textVal = null;
        NodeList nl =  ele.getElementsByTagName(tagName);
        if (nl != null && nl.getLength() > 0) {
            Element el = (Element) nl.item(0);
            textVal = ((Node) el).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
        }

        return textVal;
    }


}
```

Below is the error i am seeing :

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at narsiRestApiTest.HttpGetter.getDoc(HttpGetter.java:49)
    at narsiRestApiTest.HttpGetter.main(HttpGetter.java:23)
[Fatal Error] :1:1: Premature end of file.
Exception in thread "main" org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Premature end of file.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at narsiRestApiTest.HttpGetter.loadXMLFromString(HttpGetter.java:71)
    at narsiRestApiTest.HttpGetter.main(HttpGetter.java:25)
```

Thanks

Comment: `Below is my .java file` Where is it?

Comment: i added in code section but its not appearing in the post. Please see below

Comment: Find a solution finally after a long struggle. Added following lines into my class and it did the trick. Note : Proxyhost mean the real pxosyhost name of your organization. It should help newbies System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "proxyhost.com");
   System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "80");
   System.setProperty("http.nonProxyHosts", "localhost|127.0.0.1");

   // HTTPS
   System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "proxyhost.com");
   System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "443");